# Calling a webpage with Curl: Moved Permanently

Tags: html, http, curl

I tried to retrieve an HTTP response from a URL on port 8080 by using Curl.

When I type the URL in my browser and inspect the response with a proxy (ZAP here) everything is good => code 200.

When I use curl like this:

curl -b "cookie_name=cookie_value" http://url:8080/some_directory

I get this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://url:8080/some_directory">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at some_ip Port 8080</address>
</body></html>
```

Why do I get a different response from the server ?

p.s: the page I'm accessing required to be identified as a user on the website

Comment: Have you examined the cookie? Is the URL in the cookie the same as the URL you are using in your `curl` call? (For example, one could be for `site.web` and the other for `www.site.web` or a numeric IP address.)

Comment: @AFH Yes the cookie is the same